# How to fetch data-attribute in foreach loop of a select-element?

Tags: jquery

```
<tr class="font-titlerow">    
<td class="fontname-col">
    <select>
    <option data-fontfamily="Abel" value="1">Abel</option>
    <option data-fontfamily="Arial" value="2">Arial</option>
    <option data-fontfamily="Arial+Black" value="3">Arial Black</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="font-titlerow">    
<td class="fontname-col">
    <select>
    <option data-fontfamily="Abel" value="1">Abel</option>
    <option data-fontfamily="Arial" value="2">Arial</option>
    <option data-fontfamily="Arial+Black" value="3">Arial Black</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

How do I loop this above select and fetch the data-fontfamily in jQuery?

```
$("tr.font-titlerow").each(function(index) {       
    var drow = $(this);

    var fontselect =drow.find("td.fontname-col").find("select");
    var fontname = fontselect.val(); //This gives the value... (1,2 or 3 in example)
    var fontfamily = fontselect.attr('data-fontfamily'); //Does not work (obviously) 

}
```

Comment: `fontselect.data('fontfamily'); `

Comment: @JohnR - that is just a replacement for attr('data-fontfamily'). It's basically the same thing :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`:selected` selector](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), as custom attribute `fontfamily` is defined on `option` element not with `select` element.

```
var fontfamily = fontselect.find('option:selected').data('fontfamily');
```

```js
$("tr.font-titlerow").each(function(index) {
  var drow = $(this);

  var fontselect = drow.find("td.fontname-col").find("select");
  var fontname = fontselect.val(); //This gives the value... (1,2 or 3 in example)
  var fontfamily = fontselect.find(':selected').data('fontfamily');
  snippet.log(fontfamily)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="font-titlerow">
    <td class="fontname-col">
      <select>
        <option data-fontfamily="Abel" value="1">Abel</option>
        <option data-fontfamily="Arial" value="2">Arial</option>
        <option data-fontfamily="Arial+Black" value="3">Arial Black</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: aha. Thanks a lot. I didn't think that it had to be :selected but obviously is has to. I was looking for a way to loop through either the options were selected or not, but this works great. Thank you!